# Design a simple l18n file but Spanish special characters are not encoding properly

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm trying to figure out how to fix my PHP's character encoding:

**If I want this to be my output:**

> Primero verifique que está ingresando el nombre de usuario y contraseña correctos. Si están bien entonces uno de los dos posibles razones: si el soporte para COPPA está habilitada y hace clic en la opción Soy menor de 13 años de edad enlace mientras se registraba entonces deberá seguir las instrucciones que recibió. Si este no es el caso, entonces su cuenta debe necesitar activación. Algunas tarjetas requieren todos los nuevos registros se activarán, ya sea por sí mismo o por el administrador antes de poder iniciar la sesión. Cuando usted se colocó él te habría dicho si se requiere activación. Si se le envió un e-mail a continuación, siga las instrucciones; si usted no ha recibido el e-mail a continuación, compruebe que su dirección de correo electrónico es válida. Una de las razones se utiliza la activación es para reducir la posibilidad de que los usuarios abusen del foro de manera anónima. Si está seguro de la dirección de correo electrónico que utilizó es válido esto contacte al administrador del foro.

**It comes out like this:**

> Primero verifique que estÃ¡ ingresando el nombre de usuario y contraseÃ±a correctos. Si estÃ¡n bien entonces uno de los dos posibles razones: si el soporte para COPPA estÃ¡ habilitada y hace clic en la opciÃ³n Soy menor de 13 aÃ±os de edad enlace mientras se registraba entonces deberÃ¡ seguir las instrucciones que recibiÃ³. Si este no es el caso, entonces su cuenta debe necesitar activaciÃ³n. Algunas tarjetas requieren todos los nuevos registros se activarÃ¡n, ya sea por sÃ­ mismo o por el administrador antes de poder iniciar la sesiÃ³n. Cuando usted se colocÃ³ Ã©l te habrÃ­a dicho si se requiere activaciÃ³n. Si se le enviÃ³ un e-mail a continuaciÃ³n, siga las instrucciones; si usted no ha recibido el e-mail a continuaciÃ³n, compruebe que su direcciÃ³n de correo electrÃ³nico es vÃ¡lida. Una de las razones se utiliza la activaciÃ³n es para reducir la posibilidad de que los usuarios abusen del foro de manera anÃ³nima. Si estÃ¡ seguro de la direcciÃ³n de correo electrÃ³nico que utilizÃ³ es vÃ¡lido esto contacte al administrador del foro.

I've tried wrapping my response with `htmlentities();`, but that didn't help at all. How can I prevent this?

Comment: What's the charset encoding for the page?

Comment: set everything to charset utf-8

Comment: I set `ini_set` to utf-8 and my meta content is utf-8. do i have to do this through the sql db as well